# Windows 8 suddenly hangs/freezes every few minutes

Tags: windows-8, freeze

I am experiencing some strange trouble with Windows 8. I have been running it for over 6 months but yesterday it started acting strangely for the first time. I have done no system changes or installations recently.

While busy with any activity, the system will freeze, with only the mouse being able to move around, after about a minute, things resume normally. This continues no matter what programs I run. I have viewed the performance in the Task Manager and everything appears normal.

I suspected that my hard drive may be the culprit, but my Fedora installation works perfectly, so I doubt it is this.

Spec: Windows 8 Pro, Asus K55V  - Intel Core i7 2.4Ghz, 8GB Ram

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This indicates a HDD problem

Answer (score 0):

Since your Linux install works, you can probably rule out a hardware issue. You have to monitor your system during the freezes to find the culprit. I suggest using Process Monitor to check what is happening under the hood when those freezes occur:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

You should also check the event manager. Do the freezes occur in safe mode? If yes then it's probably a problem rooted in the operating system's system files. If not, then it's most likely a driver or 3rd party software issue.

You say they occur with any activity. Does this include the time when the PC is idle? Did you check task manager's performance graph after the freezes? Is the CPU maxed out?

This problem could also be due to malware running in the background and recording or reacting to your activity such as a keylogger, backdoor trojan or worm. To be sure you should check your system for malicious tools and programs with Hijackthis or Autoruns:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Google HijackThis. The site doesn't let me post more than two links...